# Browsersync Https proxy will not inject css or reload browser

Tags: proxy, mamp, devops, browser-sync, gulp-browser-sync

So I am proxying a MAMP SSL server with browser-sync, and I can not for the life of me figure out why it will not stream my css changes or reload for javascript. My current configuration works just fine if I do not use https via MAMP. Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my Gulp Configuration:

```
function server(done) {
  browser.init({
    port: PORT,
    proxy: {
        target: PROXY,
    },
    logLevel: 'debug',
  });
  done();
}

function watch() {
  gulp.watch('src/scss/**/*.scss').on('all', sass);
  gulp.watch('src/js/**/*.js').on('all', gulp.series(javascript, browser.reload));
}
```

Where Port is 8000 (probably not significant, as letting browser sync choose this automatically didn't change anything)
And Proxy is https://mysite.dev

Also, my gulp sass function pipes to `browsersync.stream`, to clarify.

Here is the output from browser sync log, everything seemed fine.

```
[13:10:28] Starting 'server'...
[BS] [debug] -> Starting Step: Finding an empty port
[13:10:28] Finished 'server' after 19 ms
[13:10:28] Starting 'watch'...
[BS] [debug] Found a free port: 3000
[BS] [debug] Setting Option: port - 3000
[BS] [debug] +  Step Complete: Finding an empty port
[BS] [debug] -> Starting Step: Getting an extra port for Proxy
[BS] [debug] +  Step Complete: Getting an extra port for Proxy
[BS] [debug] -> Starting Step: Checking online status
[BS] [debug] Resolved www.google.com, setting online: true
[BS] [debug] Setting Option: online - true
[BS] [debug] +  Step Complete: Checking online status
[BS] [debug] -> Starting Step: Resolve user plugins from options
[BS] [debug] +  Step Complete: Resolve user plugins from options
[BS] [debug] -> Starting Step: Set Urls and other options that rely on port/online status
[BS] [debug] Setting multiple Options
[BS] [debug] +  Step Complete: Set Urls and other options that rely on port/online status
[BS] [debug] -> Starting Step: Setting Internal Events
[BS] [debug] +  Step Complete: Setting Internal Events
[BS] [debug] -> Starting Step: Setting file watchers
[BS] [debug] +  Step Complete: Setting file watchers
[BS] [debug] -> Starting Step: Merging middlewares from core + plugins
[BS] [debug] Setting Option: middleware - List []
[BS] [debug] +  Step Complete: Merging middlewares from core + plugins
[BS] [debug] -> Starting Step: Starting the Server
[BS] [debug] Proxy running, proxing: https://districtplus.dev:8890
[BS] [debug] Running mode: PROXY
[BS] [debug] +  Step Complete: Starting the Server
[BS] [debug] -> Starting Step: Starting the HTTPS Tunnel
[BS] [debug] +  Step Complete: Starting the HTTPS Tunnel
[BS] [debug] -> Starting Step: Starting the web-socket server
[BS] [debug] Setting Option: clientEvents - List [ "scroll", "scroll:element", "input:text", "input:toggles", "form:submit", "form:reset", "click" ]
[BS] [debug] +  Step Complete: Starting the web-socket server
[BS] [debug] -> Starting Step: Starting the UI
[BS] [debug] Setting Option: session - 1504721428890
[BS] [UI] Starting Step: Setting default plugins
[BS] [UI] Step Complete: Setting default plugins
[BS] [UI] Starting Step: Finding a free port
[BS] [UI] Step Complete: Finding a free port
[BS] [UI] Starting Step: Setting options also relevant to UI from BS
[BS] [UI] Step Complete: Setting options also relevant to UI from BS
[BS] [UI] Starting Step: Setting available URLS for UI
[BS] [debug] Getting option via path: urls
[BS] [UI] Step Complete: Setting available URLS for UI
[BS] [UI] Starting Step: Starting the Control Panel Server
[BS] [UI] Using port 3001
[BS] [UI] Step Complete: Starting the Control Panel Server
[BS] [UI] Starting Step: Add element events
[BS] [UI] Step Complete: Add element events
[BS] [UI] Starting Step: Registering default plugins
[BS] [UI] Step Complete: Registering default plugins
[BS] [UI] Starting Step: Add options setting event
[BS] [UI] Step Complete: Add options setting event
[BS] [debug] +  Step Complete: Starting the UI
[BS] [debug] -> Starting Step: Merge UI settings
[BS] [debug] Setting Option: urls - Map { "local": "https://localhost:3000", "external": "https://192.168.1.101:3000", "ui": "http://localhost:3001", "ui-external": "http://192.168.1.101:3001" }
[BS] [debug] +  Step Complete: Merge UI settings
[BS] [debug] -> Starting Step: Init user plugins
[BS] [debug] Setting Option: userPlugins - 
[BS] [debug] +  Step Complete: Init user plugins
[Browsersync] Proxying: https://districtplus.dev:8890
[Browsersync] Access URLs:
 ---------------------------------------
       Local: https://localhost:3000
    External: https://192.168.1.101:3000
 ---------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://192.168.1.101:3001
```